# Captcha timeout

Tags: go, captcha

Why do I need a captcha timeout implementation. For what it is good for?

Look on github golang captcha [link](https://github.com/dchest/captcha), expiration time is here 10 minutes. For which reason do the programmer implement the expiration time for captcha.

Comment: why is this downvoted? It's a legitimate question.

Comment: This addresses the case where the user is not a robot, but may become a robot if given enough time. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> [package captcha](http://godoc.org/github.com/dchest/captcha)
>
> import "github.com/dchest/cap
>
> To make captchas one-time, the package includes a memory storage that
>   stores captcha ids, their solutions, and expiration time. Used
>   captchas are removed from the store immediately after calling Verify
>   or VerifyString, while unused captchas (user loaded a page with
>   captcha, but didn't submit the form) are collected automatically after
>   the predefined expiration time.

Read the `captcha` package documentation.

Comment: I read the documentation, but I do not see sense, why expiration time is implemented. It has something to do with security?

Comment: No. Given the weird design of `captcha.Store` and how it's the user's responsibility to manage its keys it makes sense to also give the user the control over a store's items expiration period.